# EntityDataSource replace * with % wildcard on queries

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have an application that uses EntityDataSource in many places.

In the EDS, I manually build the Where clause based on user input from TextBox'es.

I would like the user to be able to enter "*" (asterisks) instead of "%" when querying data.

Is there an easy as using Entity SQL or the EDS itself to do a search/replace? I know I could actually change the TextBox after the data is entered, but when the user sees his text was changed from an * to a % I don't think he will understand.

I have tried using the T-SQL Replace command and doing something like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDSParts" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=TTEntities" DefaultContainerName="TTEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Parts"
    OrderBy="it.ID DESC"
    Where ="(CASE
                WHEN (@PartNumber IS NOT NULL) THEN
                    it.[Number] LIKE REPLACE(@PartNumber, "*", "%")
                ELSE
                    it.[ID] IS NOT NULL
            END)">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PartNumber" Type="String"
            ControlID="txtPartNumberQuery" PropertyName="Text" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

But I get a "Server tag is not well formed" message. I can't find an equivalent "replace" function in the Entity SQL reference....

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to change double to single quotes -  `"*"` and `"%"` to `'*'` and `'%'` ? Perhaps this removes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle page postback and modify content of txtPartNumberQuery. EntityDataSource can work only with % (because it builds ESQL query) so you have to change * to % in your codebehind before you execute databinding.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that. That is why I mentioned it. :) I dont have much experience doing this, but I thought about overriding the EDS class and modifying the method that builds the Where clause. Theoretically, it should be possible....

Comment: That is the reason why I have never used EntityDataSource, LinqDataSource or SqlDataSource in real code. I always needed some level of control over binding so i did it fully manually or I used ObjectDataSource and wrap my query logic to custom object used by data source.

Comment: I hear ya. I have been writing an application for 8 months now and this is the last hurdle. I have used EntityDataSource exclusively. I haev some createive tricks in there :) I would say I was about 25% faster using EDS versus my experience with ODS. It has saved me alot of time of the development life cycle. Although, there hgave been about 3 instances like this that stumped me for a couple of days. If I dont figure it out, I will just chage it in the post back and train the users what is going on. No huge loss...

Answer (score 1):

Sluama - Your suggestion fixed it! Such an obvious answer. The " was terminating the Where clause string. I could have sworn I tried that, but I guess not. Becuase, I just happened to come back to this question and saw your answer and it works!

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDSParts" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=TTEntities" DefaultContainerName="TTEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Parts"
    OrderBy="it.ID DESC"
    Where ="(CASE
                WHEN (@PartNumber IS NOT NULL) THEN
                    it.[Number] LIKE REPLACE(@PartNumber, '*', '%')
                ELSE
                    it.[ID] IS NOT NULL
             END)">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PartNumber" Type="String"
            ControlID="txtPartNumberQuery" PropertyName="Text" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```