# How To Handle An EntityDataSource Programatically with LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I've checked out the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404748%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

[EntityDataSource replace * with % wildcard on queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632512/entitydatasource-replace-with-wildcard-on-queries)

I'm creating a page where a user will perform a search by selecting multiple options from the web page, click the search button, and a GridView will be populated. I'd like to run the GridView off an EntityDataSource to make paging and sorting easier.

My queries will look like this, but with more WHERE clauses:

```
var query = context.new_certification.Where(c => c.id == applicationId);
```

The MSDN link indicates my queries should go in the "OnQueryCreated" event. I guess I'm just not understanding how to put this all together. Personally, I don't like setting up an EDS in my HTML anyway. Code-behind feels more logical. Anyway, I get how to build my query from user input, but not how to bind it to the EDS and execute it.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like maybe I should use an ObjectDataSource vs EntityDateSource?